# Perl: how to portably reserve a TCP port (so there will be a non-available URL)

Tags: windows, perl, unix, networking, tcp

I'm the maintainer of the [XML-LibXSLT](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXSLT) module and one of the tests needs to access a non-existing URL. Problem was that someone reported that on their system the URL existed, so I decided to allocate a random port on localhost where I'm sure there will be no web-service. It was done like that:

```
# We reserve a random port to make sure the localhost address is not
# valid. See:
#
# https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=52422

my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    Proto => 'tcp',
);

my $port = $sock->sockport();

$file = "http://localhost:${port}/allow.xml";
```

Now, the problem is that $port is defined and valid (to the value of a reserved port) on Linux, but it does not appear to work on Windows - see this bug report - https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=71456 . My question is: how can I reserve a new, random, not-yet-occupied port portably across UNIXes, Mac OS X and Windows in Perl 5?

Regards,

Shlomi Fish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to `bind` to the loopback address using port 0 (so that a port will be allocated to you). For bonus points you may want to try to `connect` the socket to itself (probably not needed anywhere, but should guarantee that it has an address)

Comment: @EJP: True, I just faintly remember Windows taking a somewhat lazy approach to port allocation, at least for `INADDR_ANY` bound sockets.

Comment: The port is allocated at bind() time.

Answer (score 4):

You want to `bind` the socket to an address+port. This which will happen if you specify a `LocalAddr` (or `LocalHost`). If you don't specify a port (or you specify port zero), a free port will be picked for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use IO::Socket::INET qw( INADDR_ANY );

my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    Proto     => 'tcp',
    LocalAddr => INADDR_ANY,
);

my $port = $sock->sockport();

say $port;  # 60110
```

I think you want to only accept connections from the loopback adapter. If so, use `INADDR_LOOPBACK` instead of `INADDR_ANY`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this small tool https://github.com/yegor256/random-tcp-port (I'm a developer). Should work in Windows, since it's ANSI C.

Comment: that is not ANSI C, C has not networking APIs, I see POSIX

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (but cannot prove from here) that on Windows the port number is not actually allocated until such time as the socket actually starts listening.

However having that socket actually listen will prevent the test from failing as rapidly as it might since the initial TCP connection would actually succeed.

Have you considered just pointing the URL at `test.example.com` instead, which is guaranteed not to exist?

Comment: [http://example.com](http://example.com) - it cannot be registered, but it does exist.

Comment: I'd rather not access an Internetworked resource here because the external network may not be avialable and because I don't want the tests to "phone" somewhere without the user's agreement.

Comment: @e.dan that's why I suggested a subdomain

Comment: @Alnitak: I may have missed it, but I could have sworn you wrote `example.com`, without the subdomain.  Did you edit your post and rewrite history after I made my comment?

Comment: @e.dan I actually edited it _before_ your comment when I realised that `example.com` does have an A record, but it was within 5m of the original post so it doesn't appear in the edit history.

Comment: Ports are allocated at bind() time, on all platforms.